# Как создать папку с файлами в корне Android

Tags: android, файлы, файловая-система

Я в андроиде всего 2 недели. Прошу подскажите.

Такие приложения как Телега, Ватсап, Вконтакте, Кейт, Aliexp - все они создают свои папки в корне Storage/emulated/0

Подскажите как я могу там же создать папку и писать в нее, для Андроида от 5 до 10?

Я пытался использовать File('storage/emulated/0') но даже если запрашиваю разрешение на чтение и запись экстернал стораж то все равно у меня нет доступа на создание своей папки

Пожалуйста, дайте короткий пример создания папки/файла в этом хранилище чтобы работало в 10 андроиде.